# Sort Excel range based on a range with Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to sort a range based on a range (ex: `range(I31:I10000")`). I get an error.

I'm using Word VBA to access an Excel file to extract data into my Word file.

```vb
With xlBook.sheets(1)

    ' searching for the Reference

    Set rg = .Cells.Find(what:="Référence")
    refRow = .Range(rg.Address).Row
    refColumn = .Range(rg.Address).Column

    Set desigAdrs = .Cells.Find(what:="Désignation")

    desigColumn = .Range(desigAdrs.Address).Column 'numero de colone Designation
    tmp = "G" & (refRow + 2) & ":I" & 10000

    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("I31:I10000") _
      , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending

    With .Sort
        .SetRange .Range(tmp)
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End With
```

I want to sort based on values because not all the rows are with text.

Comment: On which line do you get an error  ? And what does it say ?

Comment: `.SetRange .Range(tmp)` is incorrect, because you are already in another `With` statement. Try `.SetRange xlBook.sheets(1).Range(tmp)`.

Comment: @Mikku i get an error at the line ".Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("I31:I10000") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending " saying "error 1004, error defined by the object or by the application" something like that

Comment: @FAB i still get an error at the line ".Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range("I31:I10000") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending " saying "error 1004,  error defined by the object or by the application"  something like that